# Как динамически создавать модальные окна

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap

Использую bootstrap. Из базы вывожу записи и напротив нее кнопочка "Редактировать", которая вызывает модальное окошко для конкретной записи (атрибут на вызов модального окна **modal-15**, где 15 - ID записи в базе). И в цикле вывожу модальные окна. И получается, что разметка окошек создается для каждой записи, и html код страницы получается просто огромный (особенно если записей много).

Какие есть более правильные способы? Буду благодарен за примеры, полезную информацию.

Comment: Создать одно модальное окно и при клике передавать в него id

Comment: @shidow может есть какие-то примеры?

Answer (score 0):

Можно каждой кнопки добавить data атрибут с id записи и при клике передавать его в input.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEXXMR

```js
$('[data-id]').click( function() {
  $('#id').val($(this).data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="1">Кнопка id 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="2">Кнопка id 2</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" id="id">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а если учесть то что еще нужно получить инфу из базу по переданному id ?

Comment: @Денис подгрузить через ajax, например